# iPhone 5 Charger Problem

Tags: battery, iphone, charging, charger, lightning

About two weeks ago, my lightning cable was torn a little but it was working so I thought I don't need to replace it immediately. A few days ago, after a night of charging, when I woke up in the morning I noticed that my charger and phone got very hot, and it didn't charge to %100, it just charged to %60 or something like that. I thought it happened because of lightning cable.

Next day, I used my mother's charger and cable, which are working properly, and it charged my phone without any problem. Yesterday, I bought a new lightning cable from Apple and attached it to my charger, I left the phone for charging for two hours, then I saw that charger and phone got hot, charged to %60, again. And I noticed that charger is making a noise like buzz.

Yesterday evening, I charged my phone to %100 with my mother's charger and cable then unplugged the device, didn't left the device charging all night. This morning, I noticed that battery decreased to %83 from %100, in stand by mode. And after an hour of using the phone (web browsing, snapchat, messaging etc.) it didn't even decreased %1. It is still %83. By the way, my charger still charges when plug it to phone but I think that it stops charging when it gets hot.

So, there are two questions I want to ask:
Did my charger get out of order and why?
Did my phone's battery get harmed by my charger (getting hot, not charging properly, buzzing)?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the charger genuine Apple or 3rd party?  I don't think anyone can tell you 'why' the charger started getting hot.  It's very possible that a bad charger can damage a battery.

Comment: It is original Apple charger, not 3rd party. I think problem can occured because of damaged lightning cable. Some of the little cables inside the lightning cable has broken and they may be touched each other. So if a short circuit happened there, it may damaged the charger but I am not sure. Thats why I'm asked.